# Is transferred vs. has transferred

Tags: sentence-meaning

Which sentence is correct?
Do you remember our friend who has transferred to new project?
(To say he transferred to new project a year ago) 
Or 
Do you remember our friend who is transferred to new project?
(To say his current status)

Answer (score 1):

> Do you remember our friend who **has/had** transferred to a new project?

is OK. Either **has** or **had** or just **transferred** could be used depending on context.

> Do you remember our friend who **has transferred** to a new project? I hope he is doing well.
>   Do you remember our friend who **had transferred** to a new project? Because of that he got a promotion.

or simply stating a fact in simple past tense:

> Do you remember our friend who **transferred** to a new project?

To say his current status, you would say:

> Do you remember our friend who **is transferring** to a new project?